# What is the maximum texture size available on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, textures, opengl-es-2.0

Anyone know the maximum texture size for the iPad?  I'm having trouble finding numbers for this.

Comment: You really need to say __what edition of the iPad__ (iPad, iPad 2, iPad 3rd gen or iPad 4th gen (to date)?)

Comment: See here http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ipad-3-benchmark-review,3156-6.html

Comment: @Rob, the accepted answer is way obsolete.  A modest suggestion - mark my answer as the accepted answer and save folks who get to this page some time.

Comment: I clearly do not use SO as much as I use to.  In any case your answer is now the accepted one @brainjam

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As a supplement to the accepted answer:

2048 was the maximum for iPad2 as well, up until iOS5.1, when it became 4096.

4096 is the maximum for iPad3, as pointed out by @badweasel in the comments.

Best to determine the limit programmatically, using

> ```
> int max;
> glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &max);
> ```

This is useful if you want your code to adapt to maximum sizes on devices or versions you haven't tried, or haven't yet been released.

Comment: I just hit this limit with my texture atlas. Noticed that on the one display object before textures stopped rendering properly my atlas height was 2046, and proximity to a power of 2 made me google, then this showed up. +1 for the GL integer query, it's exactly what I wanted :-)

Comment: For the iPad3 ("the new iPad") it returns 4096.

Comment: The code is not working for me. glGetIntegerv doesn't modify the value of max, glError is returning 0. Am I missing something? I am calling this in the app delegate at starting.

Comment: @louissmr, I'm not very much of GL user these days, but you probably need to set up a GL context before this works.

Comment: Thank you @brainjam, It makes sense. I am not using OpenGL in my app at all, but I still needing the max texture size for determine the max resolution image size to be loaded without using tiles. Should creating a context has any side effect? I guess that I can create the context, invoke glGetIntegerv and then destroy the context.

Answer (score 16):

The iPad 2 supports OpenGL ES 2.0 and 2048 x 2048 textures.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/AboutThePlatform/AboutThePlatform.html

Comment: Yeah, the answer was based on preliminary and incorrect specs. Nice catch. +1

Comment: Complete specs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html

Comment: -1: You didn't say __what iPad__.  iPad changes so much internally, they may as well be completely different devices with completely distinct names, like "iPad" for one, and "myPad" for the next one.

Comment: The iPad 2 had 512MB, and iPad 3 has [1G of shared RAM](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ipad-3-benchmark-review,3156-6.html).  You will not run out of memory after 3 2048x2048 textures.

Comment: @bobobobo I make 2048*2048*4/(1024*1024) = 2*2*4 = 16 mb per texture. So room for quite a few more than three.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more recent resource from Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/metal/limits/

It has a lot of information about graphical limitations. If you want to know the maximum texture size for iOS, find the entry for **"Maximum 2D texture width and height"**.

It depends on what operating systems you are targeting. For example, if you want to support iOS 8 and higher you are restricted to the iOS 8 limit for 2D textures of 4096 x 4096 pixels even though later versions of iOS can support larger textures.