# OpenGL ES 2 - one big vs multiple small textures atlas. What's better performance wise?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing a game in Android using an [already existing engine](http://www.andengine.org).

I have to use big textures for my animations, and i'm wondering what's better performance wise.
The new version of the engine supports npot textures(in case you ask yourself why i'm using such resolutions).

Is it better to have multiple 2330x1100 texture atlases or only one 2330x(1100 x number_of_textures_i_need) texture atlas?
Does this choice influence load time?(i think the memory they require is the same, since they contain the same number of pixel)

I read somewhere that switching textures can be a slow operation..

side quests:

1) are pot textures more efficient(in an enviroment build so that it can handle npot textures)?

2) can i hit some dimension/memory limit using just one texture?

Comment: There shouldn't be much difference for using one big texture or separating them. As long as you upload all textures beforehand that is. Updating such a big texture during rendering could be quite time consuming operation. As for memory usage, using RGB_565 for example, one such texture you have takes roughly 5MB of memory - so yes - you might meet some memory limits.

Comment: @harism thanks! Yes, it is loaded only once at the start of the app. Is vmemory that low on mobile devices?

Comment: Actually it might be the case memory usage isn't your biggest concern but image dimensions instead. If on IPad2 texture size limit is [2048x2048](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505186/what-is-the-maximum-texture-size-available-on-the-ipad), I wouldn't be very surprised if it was less on Android devices in general.

Answer (score 1):

one big texture should be better because loading and activating is slow because of the memory upload to the video memory. It also should use less energy and so enhances user experience ;-)

Try it - and write a long running test to prove it.