# SpriteKit textureFromNode returns black image

Tags: sprite-kit

Here is the sample code:

```
    SKNode* node = [SKNode node];
    node.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild: node];

    SKSpriteNode *sprite1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    sprite1.position = CGPointMake(-900.0, -900.0);
    [node addChild: sprite1];

    SKSpriteNode *sprite2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    sprite2.position = CGPointMake(900.0, 900.0);
    [node addChild: sprite2];        

    [self runAction: [SKAction sequence: @[[SKAction waitForDuration: 3.0], [SKAction runBlock:^{

        SKTexture* texture = [self.view textureFromNode: node];
        SKSpriteNode* ts = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture: texture];
        ts.xScale = 1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        ts.yScale = 1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        [self addChild: ts];
    }]]]];
```

As soon as I put two sprites far apart from each other which makes accumulated frame of container node larger, I get black texture?

Comment: how far apart? Textures have a maximum size of 2048x2048 points. If the accumulated frame is larger than this the texture may not be created at all. Check if textureFromNode: returns nil.

Comment: The maximum texture size actually depends on the device, most current ios devices can handle 4096, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505186/what-is-the-maximum-texture-size-available-on-the-ipad

Answer (score 2):

The size of the texture generated by this method is based on the size of the node in scene coordinates, not the pixel size of the screen it occupies. So if your node occupies 10000x10000 scene space this method will try to generate a 10000x10000 texture. This breaches the 4096x4096 max texture size limit and rather than fail the method returns a black texture.

It is possible to control the size of the texture generated by scaling the node down just before the textureFromNode call and then scaling it back up afterwards. E.g:

```
//paintNode is 1000x1000 in scene coordinates
self.paintNode.setScale(0.5)
let texture = SKView().texture(from: self.paintNode)
//texture size is 500x500
self.paintNode.setScale(1)
```

When trying to avoid the 4096x4096 limit it is also important to take into account the scale factor of the device. On an iPhone 6 plus with a scale factor of 3 (retina HD) a SKTexture of size 500x500px will internally be 1500x1500px. I hit this trying to generate a texture for a scene of width 1600. It worked fine on every device except the HD retina devices. Any texture generated for scene space larger than 1365 caused a black texture. 1365 x 3 = 4095, just below the 4096x4096 maximum.

Comment: Nice overview of the device specific limits: https://developer.apple.com/metal/limits/