# Maximum file size for sprites in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

What's the maximum size a file can be for a sprite? I have a background for a level that's 9200x640 and when I try to load the page it's on, the app crashes. If this is an issue, what can I do to resolve it? If not, what should I do in order for it to work?

Comment: Related and most likely your answer: [What is the maximum texture size available on the iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505186/what-is-the-maximum-texture-size-available-on-the-ipad). Your texture is way too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the device (usually 2048×2048 or 4096×4096).  For large images like the one you are using, you really need to use tiled images.  Ray Wenderlich has an example here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x